# How to open a file using openfiledialog in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How to open a file using openfiledialog

The below is my code:

```
Dim Fs As StreamReader
    With OpenFD
        .FileName = ""
        .Title = "Open Text File"
        .InitialDirectory = "c:\"
        .Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
    Dim path As String = OpenFD.FileName
    txtin.Text = OpenFD.FileName
    Fs = New StreamReader(path)
```

I can get the path of the file. But not able to open file. Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the entire text file, you can use [`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx). You can do so like this:

```
Dim readText() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

The file will then get stored into your string array, and you can access each line by index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work.

---

```
Dim sr As StreamReader

'Supposing you haven't already set these properties...
    With OFD
        .FileName = ""
        .Title = "Open a text file..."
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"
    End With

    If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            sr = New StreamReader(OFD.Filename)
            txtInFile.Text = OFD.Filename
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("The file specified could not be opened." & VbNewLine & "Error message:" & VbNewLine & VbNewLine & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OK, "File Could Not Be Opened!")
        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a stream to read a text file simply use File.ReadAllText(), here are my codes that work for me

```
Private Sub OpenFileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenFileButton.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select TEXT File"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Query"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```