# OpenFileDialog (Cancel/Close) File Not Found Crash

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

This is my code:

```
Private Sub HuraButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HuraButton1.Click
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "Select a Text File..."
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Files"
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim Lookfor As String = ""
    Dim result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If openFileDialog1.FileName = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        MsgBox("File Not Found")
    End If
    If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
        MsgBox("Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    End If

End Sub
```

Error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The File'D:\1DesktopFILE\RobeVisualStudio\ShaadyyTool\bin\Debug\Select a Text File' Not Found.
```

I want to make sure that those who close the "OpenFileDialog1" The app doesn't crash. 
I Don't know why it doesn't work,
Can you write the correct code thanks.
Sorry for my eng.

Comment: this will help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Notwithstanding the correct notes on control flow below... what happens if the file is deleted between the time it's selected in the dialog and the time you need to process it?  Even with correct control flow, you pretty much always need to be prepared to handle file system exceptions any time you do file access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a file using openfiledialog in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495078/how-to-open-a-file-using-openfiledialog-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this is what you want

```
Private Sub HuraButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HuraButton1.Click
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *txt"
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\"
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Files"
    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'file selected now process it 
        Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim Lookfor As String = ""
        If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
            MsgBox("Found")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found")
        End If
    Else
        'file not selected or user cancelled 
        MsgBox("file not selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = "Select a Text File..."
```

i think you miss understood the above statement to set as a dialog box's title ...it is not what you think...rather  it is used to find/select  a file in the opened directory

Comment: What Should i do?

Comment: If I do not select anything,It gives me this error (System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid empty path name.')

Comment: comment that line and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You want to make some changes to this.  Use the dialog result to determine if you should move forward.  If they didn't select a file, don't do the code.

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    Dim Findstring as String = IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim Lookfor As String = ""

    If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor ) Then
        MsgBox("Found")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    End If

End If
```

Comment: OK sorry bro. Thanks

Comment: If it works for you...please accept...also not sure what you want in the look for... obviously not blank

Answer (score 0):

Since the OpenFileDialog uses unmanaged code you really should put it in a `Using` block.

```
Using openFileDialog1 as OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *txt"
    ...
End Using
```

That way you can be sure that it is removed from memory completely, even if there is an exception inside the `Using` block.

Then you should give your OpenFileDialog an element to which it will open modally, otherwise it can happen that your OpenFileDialog vanishes in the background and your application seems unresponsive (because it waits for the OpenFileDialog to return but the user doesn't see that).
Since you seem to be in a `Form` anyway, just do

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Then you should check for the return value of `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` and only proceed if there really has a file been selected.

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.Ok Then
    ...
End If
```

If the result of `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` is not `DialogResult.Ok` then `openFileDialog1.FileName` might be `Nothing`.

I hope this helps a little bit.