# How to do nothing after pressing cancel button

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

When user clicks on the CANCEL button from the OpenFileDialog, the program crashes (I think it's because the program is continuing).  How can I make it so when user clicks on CANCEL, it just closes the dialog but not exit the program?

```
        Stream myStream;

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = ofd.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                string strfilename = ofd.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
                txtMain.Text = filetext;
                textBox2.Text = Path.GetFileName(strfilename);
            }
        }
```

When user clicks on CANCEL:
Actual result: Error
Expected result: dialog screen closes and return to the main form

Comment: Did you set breakpoints, what line is the issue?

Comment: There's something else going on here besides the posted code.  Can you show more code and/or explain more about your app?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422716/openfiledialog-cancel-close-file-not-found-crash)?

Comment: Sorry, im not sure how to do that.  There's nothing wrong with the line.  But i feel like i need to add an ELSE or if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) .  Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Again...nothing wrong with what you posted.  Show us what happens **AFTER** this bit.

Comment: Well, build your program as debug build and run it in the debugger. The debugger should be able to provide you with addtional information regarding what the actual error is and where it actually originates from. If not familiar with Visual Studio's debugger yet, take some time with a handy guide such as this: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) (you can select different topics of the guide on the left-hand side menu visible in the guide). The code in the question is NOT CAUSING the error

Comment: `if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` you are already checking what the result is, if user cancels it wouldn't confirm to the check and that code inside will not get executed... `When user clicks on CANCEL: Actual result: Error Expected result: dialog screen closes and return to the main form`, this doesn't make much sense... As @Idle_Mind mentioned, you need to show all code after all this.

Comment: The next code is a substring:

if (txtMain.Substring(20, 2) == "21")
{ 
  ..... code here
}

So what's happening is it's processing that code, but since user cancelled, txtMain is empty.

Comment: Yeah, but what if the text in txtMain is less than 22 characters in length? Have you thought about that? (I am not going to speculate any further, see my previous comment. If you want to substantially increase your chances of getting helpful answers, please provide at least a [mcve])

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  The problem was the rest of the code was outside the IF statement.  After moving it inside, it finally did what's it should.  Sorry. Rookie mistake